# Which is optimum: a char array uninitialized but null terminated after read() or initialize all elements with zero and then read() for C++

Tags: c++, optimization, stack-memory

Which among the following code snippet is best practice, optimum(CPU utilization), safe, readable:

```
{
    char buffer[10];
    ssize_t bytes = read(0, buffer, 9);
    if(bytes > 0)
    {
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        // return, break, continue
    }
    // more business logic
}
```

or

```
{
    char buffer[10] = {};
    ssize_t bytes = read(0, buffer, 9);
    if(bytes <= 0)
    {
        // return, break, continue
    }
    // more business logic
}
```

In which architecture these are preferred or discouraged.

Lets say for comparison we `g++ -S -fverbose-asm` and `as -alhnd`.
This can help assembly code comparison for optimum code choice.
I will add the results of it soon.

Comment: You don't need to initialize the buffer before reading into it. Both programs do exactly the same thing.

Comment: `unsigned int bytes = read(0, buffer, 9);`?!?  `read()` does not return an unsigned value.  It returns `ssize_t`.

Comment: I would go with the first variant, since initializing the whole buffer with zeroes is not necessary and a waste of resources.

Comment: Write what is easy to understand, and worry about micro-optimizations when you prove they're a problem with profiling.

Comment: I always use the first form, and I imagine it to be more efficient.  In the second form, the compiler typically has to emit code to zero out the whole array, and that's unnecessary given that most of the array is about to be overwritten.  But do heed Jabberwocky's comment: between the `read` call and the `buffer[bytes] = '\0'` assignment you need a test to see if `bytes` is less than 0.

Comment: `unsigned int bytes{ read(0, buffer, 9) };` so the compiler can help you notice the programming mistake.

Comment: Which does your profiler tell you is faster?  And is this hitting often enough in your code to even care?

Comment: @273K yes, you are right. I updated it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky stack memory cannot be all zeros right? In cases like it was used earlier by some other function stack?

Comment: @MithunB _"stack memory cannot be all zeros right?"_ I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean, but yes, stack memory contains garbage values by default, IOW it can contain anything, for example some super secret password used somewhere in a previous function call.

Comment: The first one with a more proper condition `if(byte >= 0)` is shown in many C books, it works for C++ too. It is significantly faster when the buffer is large and stream data is already fetched/buffered. For example, sockets.

Comment: Neither. Don’t initialize the buffer and don’t null-terminate it either. Just use the length returned by `read()`. That’s what it’s for.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a too early micro optimization question. Readability matters more than efficiency here, and IMHO the first version is more clear about the intent: read a bunch of characters and null terminate it.

Furthermore, zero initialization of a buffer requires to write every byte. Not a very heavy task because it can happen at a very low level, but probably slightly heavier than writing one single byte.